# Getting blank page trying to see WSDL from WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wsdl

I can connect to my WCF service hosted on IIS when I use VS to generate a client proxy but when I look through the browser I get a blank page, the same when I append ?WSDL. What am I doing wrong? I need to see the WSDL

My service interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IObjectService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "/GetTrade"
        )]
    GetTradeResponse GetTrade(GetTradeRequest request);
}
```

And my web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ObjectServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <!-- This section is optional with the default configuration         model introduced in .NET Framework 4 -->
      <service name="ObjectServiceApi.ObjectService" behaviorConfiguration="ObjectServiceBehaviour">

        <!-- This endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host:http://localhost/ObjectService.svc  -->
        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding"
                  contract="ObjectServiceApi.Interface.IObjectService" />

      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: What is the URL you were calling? Maybe you you have an ending `slash? /` on the URL like this: `http://localhost:PORT/ObjectService.svc/`

Comment: http://10.220.175.59:8085/ObjectService.svc - I've tried with and without the end slash. Is there some sort of IIS tracing I can turn on to see if any errors are being thrown?

Comment: You can try to set `security mode="None"` and `transport clientCredentialType="None"`. Maybe there is a problem with the authentication.

Comment: Another idea would be to completely remove the `<services />` part and changing `<binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">` to `<binding>`

Since you don't need these attributes, except you want to modify your endpoints (this might be the problem as well).

Comment: I think you might be onto something with the authentication. I just remembered I recently removed my MEX endpoint which was open to anonymous but my standard service requires windows authentication. Since removing my MEX endpoint I can no longer connect to the service via VS, it gives a 401 unauthorized exception. How can I make WSDL publicly available while locking down my service?

Comment: I do not think it has something to do with the authentication. I do rather think it has to do something with the endpoint you are exposing. Try to remove the whole endpoint configuration from your `web.config` and let `.NET` handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Do make sure that in IIS you've enabled the Authorization Method on your application.

I am almost (!) sure that you can call your WSDL if you change your `web.config` to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What do the protocolMappings and webserver blocks do? Surely I still have to specify an endpoint for IIS or how will IIS know where the service is?

Comment: `protocolMapping` defines which protocol has to use which binding.
The `webServer` part is actually not needed (copied from my `web.config`).

You don't have to specify an endpoint in your web.config. IIS will handle it automatically for you if you don't define one.

Comment: The `<protocalMapping>` element is not needed if you're using `basicHttpBinding`, as that is the default for WCF over `http`.

Comment: Thank you @Tim didn't know that!